# Convert 0-5 V input signal to 0-100% PWM

Tags: dc, control, speed

I am attempting to speed control two aftermarket DC brushed fuel pumps in an automobile.  The OEM pump control works in the following manner:

When driving conditions demand a decrease in fuel supply, the fuel
pump control module (FPCM) reduces the supply voltage to the fuel
pump. When driving conditions demand an increase in fuel supply
(during engine start, low engine coolant temperature or high load),
the supply voltage to the fuel pump is increased.

To effect this, the factory ECU spends a low current 0-5 V signal to the OEM fuel pump control module.  The OEM logic is very simple and drives the pumps at three speeds which will call low, medium, and high. This translates into roughly 8.5 V, 10 V, or 14 V (battery voltage).

With an aftermarket ECU, all my fuel pump control issues are easily solved. But I am trying to do this using the factory ECU to speed control the pumps, but not drive them. I will be bypassing the factory Fuel Pump Control Module because it can't safely support this load.  I am also trying to greatly simplify the wiring of installing these aftermarket pumps.

I will be driving the fuel pumps using a high current MOSFET Sink Source Driver made by Racegrade. It contains qty4 10 amp outputs that can only be switched to the low side and are all PWM capable. Each pump will be driven by TWO 10 amp channels and pump draws a maximum of 15 amps at it's peak pressure.

Now here is my question:

I need a module or solution that would take the 0-5V pump control from the factory ECU, and then convert that to a 0-100 low side PWM signal. The SSD's output is activated when the control wire is pulled down to 0V.

Here is a wiring diagram of the SSD:

[image: SSD]

Thank you an advance for any input you guys can provide.  I am not an electrical engineer but I am very interested in circuits and vehicle control systems.

Comment: Multiply by 20....

Comment: You can read the voltage with an MCU's ADC input and retransmit it as PWM.

Comment: With the modifications you are planning, are the ECU condition still valid? You might want to just ignore this feature (in your race car).  =-D

Comment: The cars we build are still full street cars, but we modify the systems to support much higher power levels.  Race-cars masquerading as street cars. :)  But one would be hard pressed to tell the difference between our 500hp cars and 1500hp cars in terms of start up, drivability, and things of that sort. So yes, we still control a majority of our builds with the factory ECU which we reprogram to suit.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, would you mind elaborating on your comment?  What would I need to accomplish what you've outlined?

Comment: Program a microcontroller. Depending on where you're starting from it could be easy or very not easy.

Comment: 100% ON time may be impossible using PWM, as it is used in increments of time. You may have to live with a 99.9% ON time. The maximum ON time is equal to 100% minus the minimum ON time. The work-around is to bit-bash the pin ON at a certain maximum pulse width.

Comment: Why is this question off-topic?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some IC like the [TL5002](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl5002.pdf) could be usefull.

Comment: I read over the spec sheet and quickly got in way over my head.

Answer (score 1):

Programming an MCU. All you'd have to learn are ADCs, timers/counters, and compare matching. I recommend an AVR as they're well supported.

Comment: You can use an Arduino, then it is really easy to learn those things.

Comment: Oh yeah that as well, you can accomplish this with very few lines of code it's probably your best bet unless you want to use that IC that @GGross mentioned, which might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Yeah I second the arduino. The arduino UNO uses PWM for "analog output", so you could literally do analog read on one pin, then analog write on a second pin, and you're done.